# Horizontal non-scrollable list using listview.builder in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to thank the flutter community for such a huge amount of knowledgebase and packages.

My question is that I would like to make a horizontal list that does not scroll like how most examples in listview.builder works.

I have successfully made the text vertically aligned with listTile, but that is not what I am looking for.

TLDR; how to make a book-like per sentence structure using itemBuilder?

---

**What I am looking for**

title1 
 anotherTitle1

longtext 1 | longtext 2 | long 
 text that contains
a very long 
list 3 | another 
very long text
 that contains
text 4 | ...

title2 
 anotherTitle2

longtext 1 | longtext 2 | long 
 text that contains
a very long 
list 3 | another 
very long text
 that contains
text 4 | ...

---

**My current code**

```
Container(
      child: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: new CustomScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            new SliverPadding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
              sliver: new SliverList(
                delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              color: new Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                new BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.black12,
                                  blurRadius: 10.0,
                                  offset: new Offset(0.0, 10.0),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Container(height: 4.0),
                                new Text(text[index].title),
                                new Container(height: 10.0),
                                new Text(text[index].anotherTitle),
                                new Separator(),                           
                                ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: text.longlist[index].longtext.length
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, position) {
                                    return Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        border: new Border (
                                          top: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)
                                        )
                                      ),
                                        child: ListTile(
                                        title: Text(text.longlist[index].longtext[position].text,),
                                            trailing: Container(
                                                width: 30.0,
                                                height: 30.0,
                                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, ),
                                                 // color: Colors.white,
                                            ),
                                            child: Center(child: Text(text.longlist[index].longtext[position].number)),
                                            ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                            ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  childCount: text.longlist[index].length,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

---

Update: After thinking about it, it is more like a Flexible Row, side by side (until container width) and then it would go to the next line.

Comment: could you add any screenshot or gif about what do you want?

Comment: I have never done this before, I don't think I have seen it.
Edit: basically, like how a bible would have verses one after the other. I have a json file that shows content in that way. and I would like to be able to show it that way.